# Outllook addin function getRegExMatches() is always returning null

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to develop a outlook add-in that finds an expression with regex in the mail body, but the getRegExMatches() always give me null.

I didn't know how to do it so I tried the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5#getregexmatches--object

the code for the rules of the example are

```xml
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" FormType="Read" ItemType="Message" />
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="fruits" RegExValue="apple|banana|coconut" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" IgnoreCase="true" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="veggies" RegExValue="tomato|onion|spinach|broccoli" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" IgnoreCase="true" />
  </Rule>
</Rule>
```

and in the javascript I can call this rule like this

```
var allMatches = Office.context.mailbox.item.getRegExMatches();
var fruits = allMatches.fruits;
var veggies = allMatches.veggies;
```

the var allMatches is the one that gives me a null, because of that the others 2 variables gives an error. This was supposed to give an array with strings, which this strings must be equals to the strings in the  rules (like apple, banana, etc).

Comment: Can you please tell us what platform you are testing this on? Outlook (Windows), Outlook (Mac) or Outlook Online (Browser?) or Mobile (iOS/Android)?

Comment: I am testing in Outlook online

Answer (score 0):

The regex rules should only work in the context of detected entities. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins. Are you running your add-in from a detected entity as a contextual add-in? If not, then use [Body.getAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-1.7#getasync-coerciontype--options--callback-) to get the body, and then try searching in the body with your regex.